# Why is there a Disciplined badge as well as Peer Pressure?

Tags: discussion, badges

I understand the value of the [Peer Pressure](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/20/peer-pressure) badge. If a post has a negative score, it means it is not a valuable one and deleting it by oneself cleans up the forum. But why give a badge for deleting one's post with a **positive** score? Or do I miss something about the working of the [Disciplined](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/19/disciplined) badge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes, score doesn't reflect actual post quality. Maybe an answer got upvoted and then you realised it was wrong. Deleting poor content *even if it loses you some rep points* is perhaps even more praiseworthy and community-minded than deleting poor content that's downvoted, which could be just to avoid losing the rep.

> As for Peer Pressure and Disciplined, they both have good motivation. One teaches that you can remove bad content; the other is to encourage removing bad content even though you'll lose some precious Official Reputation Points.
>
> -- [from main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107633/278659)